# Retargeting pkcs11 keys to jcecsp in nCipher HSM

Tags: pkcs#11, jce, hsm

Using PKCS11 api, I am able to generate symmetric keys (DES3) but now I need to retarget these keys to jcecsp for an application which only uses nCipher JCE provider  to access the HSM. I realise that `jcecsp` is not in the recognised app list of `--retarget` command.

So my questions is: is there a way to add `jcecsp` as an supported application for `generatekey --retarget` command? or this is simply not possible in nShield HSM?

I got this error output:

```
$ generatekey --retarget jcecsp
ERROR: sorry, application jcecsp is not currently usable
```

Comment: Did you ever get this issue resolved? If so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

jcecsp is a little weird in that operations need to go through Java's KeyStore API.  You might be able to use Java keytool's -importkeystore option with SunPKCS11 as source, and nCipher.sworld as destination.  If this works, you'll have effectively retargeted the key.  The Java layer, working through the keystore file, ensures that key can be found again when JCE tries to access it.

You'll be dancing with a lot of options... SunPKCS11 docs are here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html and see the Thales docs for what to feed it about the nCipherKM side.